# tkinter считывать нажатие на фигуру

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Программка, где надо кликать на кружочки успеть, и я вообще хз, как сделать так, что бы считывалось нажатие на фигуру, конечно можно именно кружок, но можно и квадрат коодинат кружка

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
import random
import time

#Начало блока окна
root = Tk()
root.geometry('960x540')
root.title("ReacPicker v1.0")
root.iconbitmap(r'D:\python\charm\учуся\venv\gg\ReacPicker v1.0\4.ico')
#Конец блока окна

#Начало блока переменных
colors = ['red','orange','green','blue']
instr = "Ае сасный"
zach = "да не зачем"
#Конец блока переменных

#Начало блока функций
def Instruct():
    messagebox.showinfo("Справка", instr)
def Zachem():
    messagebox.showinfo("Справка", zach)

def Start():
    Krujki()
    button1['state'] = 'disabled'

def f(event):
    print(event.x, event.y)

def Krujki():
    global a,b,r
    holst.delete(ALL)
    a = random.randint(5, 640)
    b = random.randint(5, 480)
    r = 25
    holst.create_oval(a,b,a+r,b+r,fill = random.choice(colors), width=0)
    root.after(1000,Krujki)

def click(event):
    #global i
    for event.x in range(event.x, event.x + 25):
        print (event.x)
    for event.y in range(event.y, event.y + 25):
        print (event.y)

    print(a, b, 111)
    print(event.x, event.y)

def Lose():
    global labelLL
    labelLL = Label(holst, text = 'ReacPicker v1.0', font = ("Ubuntu", 20))
    labelLL.place(x= 50, y= 90)
#Конец блока функций


#Начало блока меню
menu1 = Menu(root)
root.configure(menu=menu1)
menu1.add_command(label = "Инструкция", command=Instruct)
menu1.add_command(label = "О программе", command=Zachem)
#Конец блока меню

holst = Canvas(root, width=670, height=500, bg='white')
label1 = Label(root, text = 'ReacPicker v1.0', font = ("Ubuntu", 14))
button1 = Button(root, text = 'Играть', font = 30,height=5, width=25,  command=Start)

#Начало блока размещения
label1.place(x= 700, y= 20)
button1.place(x= 700, y= 130)
holst.place(x= 10, y= 10)
#Конец блока размещения

holst.bind('<Button-1>', click)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @Vladimir Извиняюсь, если вопрос глупый, но что делать с этим? (я совсем новичок) NameError: name 'circle' is not defined ( тоже было с sqrt, но я импортировал математику и вроде все заработало)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы отслеживать нажатие на фигуру на Canvas, можно использовать привязку к событию фигуры с помощью метода [`tag_bind`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.tag_bind-method):

```
import random
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
holst = Canvas(root, width=670, height=500, bg='white')
holst.pack()

colors = ['red','orange','green','blue']


def click_on_circle(event):
    print('Click on circle')


def Krujki():
    holst.delete(ALL)
    a = random.randint(5, 640)
    b = random.randint(5, 480)
    r = 25
    krug = holst.create_oval(a, b, a+r, b+r, fill=random.choice(colors), width=0)

    holst.tag_bind(krug, '<Button-1>', click_on_circle)

    root.after(1000,Krujki)


Krujki()
root.mainloop()
```

Функция `click_on_circle` будет срабатывать при клике по кружку. Будет работать и если заменить овал на прямоугольник (`create_rectangle`) или многоугольник (`create_polygon`).

Answer (score 0):

Сначала определите место нажатие мыши.

```
 def click(event):
    x = event.x
    y = event.y
```

Дальше проверьте находятся ли эти координаты в круге.

У вас есть координаты центра круга `circle.x`, `circle.y`, есть радиус круга `R`.

Все что вам остается - узнать расстояние от `circle.x`, `circle.y` до `x`, `y` и сравнить его с `R`.

Расчет расстояния от центра до точки клика:

`l = sqrt(pow((circle.x - x), 2) + pow((circle.y - y), 2))`

Если `l < R` - попал в круг. Иначе - не попал.